# azure ai studio error: Missing header 'chatgpt_url' in request

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api, azure-openai

Greetings fellow developers,

I'm facing an obstacle while using the ChatGPT Playground Preview within Azure OpenAI Studio. As someone new to both OpenAI and the Azure platform, I'm seeking assistance with a specific error that I encountered. Here's the problem I'm facing and the steps I've taken:

Problem:
When attempting to utilize the session chat feature in the ChatGPT Playground Preview, I received the following error message:

"Missing header 'chatgpt_url' in request."

Setup and Steps Taken:

I'm utilizing Azure OpenAI Studio and have successfully integrated external data from my Azure subscription using a storage service and cognitive search service.
In an effort to explore the capabilities of the ChatGPT Playground Preview, I initiated the session chat functionality.
However, the mentioned error message appeared, leaving me unsure of its cause and the next course of action.
Your insights, suggestions, or solutions regarding this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your assistance in advance!

Best regards,
Suma

Answer (score 0):

Hi the problem arises when you have a Private Endpoint enabled please submit a ticket to Microsoft to correct this! It also happens when you try to reach it via an API call with datasource enabled.

Comment: Thanks @Kamal. Need some clarity.

Does your response means PE for Open AI service is supported by raising support ticket?

Also, is PE for Cognitive Search service also supported?

When I use Cognitive Search with PE from OpenAI Portal, UI hangs. So not sure what is supported and what is not.